# How to use NSolve while specifying the range of one variable

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I have an equation that uses three variables that I have defined as follows: `b[l_, m_, lt_] := 0.025 * (((1 - m)*l)^(-1/2))*((1 - m)*lt) - 5`.

After this definition, I am attempting to solve this equation using NSolve --> `NSolve[{b[l, m, lt] = 0}, {l, m, lt}, Reals]`.

This results in an error of `NSolve: 3 is not a valid variable` with an additional output of `NSolve[{0, False}, {l, 3, lt}, Reals]`. However, this is not a massive deal since the problem definition I am working with requires 0<=m<=1, which negates the issue of NSolve not working when m=3. The issue that I am running into is I cannot find a way in which to have the parameters of NSolve reflect the bounds that I want to place on m.

For instance, `NSolve[{b[l, 0 <= m <= 1, lt] = 0}, {l, m, lt}, Reals]`
and
`NSolve[{b[l, m, lt] = 0, 0 <= m <= 1}, {l, m, lt}, Reals]` both give the exact same error and result, while `NSolve[{b[l, m, lt] = 0}, {l, 0 <= m <= 1, lt}, Reals]` just gives me empty brackets.

Any suggestions on what my parameters should be? Thank you so much!

Comment: better not use `l` as variable names, it looks like `1` which makes the code hard to read. Also, are you sure you want to write `NSolve[{b[l, m, lt] = 0}` instead of `NSolve[{b[l, m, lt] == 0}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

b[l_, m_, lt_] := 1/40*(((1 - m)*l)^(-1/2))*((1 - m)*lt) - 5

sol = Solve[{b[l, m, lt] == 0, 0 <= m <= 1}, {l, m, lt}, Reals] // 
  Simplify
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
Assuming[{l > 0, 0 <= m < 1}, b[l, m, lt] == 0 /. sol[[1]] // 
  Simplify]

(* True *)
```

To find 10 instances

```
inst = FindInstance[{b[l, m, lt] == 0, 0 <= m < 1, l > 0}, 
  {l, m, lt}, Reals, 10]

(* {{l -> 532, m -> 49/102, lt -> 400 Sqrt[13566/53]}, {l -> 638, m -> 0,
   lt -> 200 Sqrt[638]}, {l -> 663, m -> 89/102, 
  lt -> 10200 Sqrt[2]}, {l -> 816, m -> 55/102, 
  lt -> 40800 Sqrt[2/47]}, {l -> 769, m -> 0, 
  lt -> 200 Sqrt[769]}, {l -> 89, m -> 0, 
  lt -> 200 Sqrt[89]}, {l -> 530, m -> 4/51, 
  lt -> 200 Sqrt[27030/47]}, {l -> 532, m -> 0, 
  lt -> 400 Sqrt[133]}, {l -> 530, m -> 0, 
  lt -> 200 Sqrt[530]}, {l -> 898, m -> 49/102, 
  lt -> 400 Sqrt[22899/53]}} *)
```

Verifying,

```
And @@ (b[l, m, lt] == 0 /. inst)

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ContourPlot3D` shows all solutions `{m,l,lt}`

```
ContourPlot3D[0 == 1/40*(((1 - m)*l)^(-1/2))*((1 -m)*lt) - 5, {m, 0, 1 }, {l, 0 , 10}, {lt, 0, 1000}, AxesLabel -> {"m", "l", "lt"}]
```

[image]